# Why does htaccess mod_rewrite always discard the query string in the target URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following logic in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule notes/(.*?) notes/?u=/$1
</IfModule>
```

However, for some reason this always removes the query string from the output. So, this is for example the result I git:

```
http://localhost:8888/notes/tifffilmtips   >   http://localhost/notes/
```

However, if I change the RewriteRule to `RewriteRule notes/(.*?) notes/u=/$1`, excluding the `?` before the `u=`, the result is:

```
http://localhost:8888/notes/tifffilmtips   >   http://localhost/notes/u=/tifffilmtips
```

So for some reason, the output always discards the generated query string. Why would this be? I've tried different flags, but I can't find one that works as expected, and I can't find reference to other people having similar problems.

---

**EDIT:**

Here's the complete htaccess with the first part working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteBase /magazine/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^notes/(.*)$ notes/?u=/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /magazine/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /magazine/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your RewriteRule to this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /magazine/wordpress/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^notes/(.*)$ notes/?u=/$1 [NC,L]    

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /magazine/wordpress/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: That's not it. The condition on the query string you define seems irrelevant, as is QSA, since I'm not looking at ways to maintain an original query string; as you can see in the examples I'm not sending in any query strings. The problem is that the query string expected in the output isn't present.

Comment: Can you try: `RewriteRule ^notes/(.*)$ notes/?u=/$1 [L,NC,R]` ?

Comment: Never test on that site, its not reliable. Test in your env. I tested this code and `http://localhost/notes/abc` became `http://localhost/notes/?u=/abc` btw do you have a .htaccess under `notes/` ?

Comment: Ah, it seems that it works! However there is a second set of rules, the basic WordPress htaccess, that now tries to find a page based on the inital url, not on the result of the first rewrite. Can I make the second rewrite use the result of the first rewrite?

Comment: Is WP installed in the DOCUMENT_ROOT? Can you post your complete .htaccess in your question?

Comment: Don't think it is, I added the htaccess including the changes you proposed.

Comment: Exact. I want /notes?u=/foo to get passed into WP.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37644/discussion-between-jasper-kennis-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 1):

If `/notes/` is being routed as a wordpress permalink, then this is going to be a bit painful as wordpress usually strips out the query string when you turn on permalinks. Take a look at [this post](http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/) which goes over why wordpress is doing this, how it's doing it, and how to work around it. Permalinks in wordpress adds an additional layer of rewriting that's internal to wordpress and query string parameters get blown away when that happens. So the fix involves adding some php code, specifically in your theme's **`functions.php`** script. Something like:

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
  $aVars[] = "u"; 
  return $aVars;
}

// hook add_query_vars function into query_vars
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

then:

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
  $aNewRules = array('notes/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=notes&u=$matches[1]');
  $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
  return $aRules;
}

// hook add_rewrite_rules function into rewrite_rules_array
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: This works yes, only internally WordPress doesn't listen to the `/notes` route any more, so it shows the default template, not the template hooked into the notes page. Think I can fix that tho.